# What is the complexity of ICE (Individual conditional expectation) on ensemble trees

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, gbm, interpretation, time-complexity

I'm evaluating different model-agnostic methods on gradient boosting or random forest model.

For Shapley, specifically TreeSHAP, the complexity is O(TLD^2) according to Lundberg et al. 2018. T: #trees, L:max #leaves, D:depth

What would be the complexity of ICE (Individual conditional expectation) on the ensemble tree models? Is there any reference or paper mentioned about the algorithm complexity?

Thanks!